# Como adicionar referências no Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, dll

Como posso referênciar dll's no visual studio code?

Estou tentando compilar um projeto c# com arquitetura MVC.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc abriu no VS Coda apenas algum arquivo ou pasta isoladamente, ou abriu no VS Code o projete inteiro com todas as pastar do projeto?

Comment: Acredito que este plugin para vscode possa ajudá-lo https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RafisTatar.addlocalnetreferences maiores informações sobre a utilização você pode achar neste post: https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-adicionar-referencia-de-dll-no-vscode-100552

Comment: Abri o protejo todo e tentei executar, como eu vim do visual studio ele perdeu todas as referências

Comment: A aqueles que estão dando negativo, por favor me ajuda a entender como posso melhorar a pergunta, fui super objetivo, mas parece que não entender do assunto é motivo para negativar.

Comment: Esse projeto você criou do zero ou baixou via GIT ou alguém lhe enviou e já continha o .csproj?

Comment: Apenas migrei do Visual Studio já contendo o .csproj. A maioria das dll's são locais.

Comment: @null ok mas NHibernate é uma DLL ou você instalou via NUGET?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não seria só adicionar o pacote via nuget? Link https://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate

```
dotnet add package NHibernate
```

Depois executar:

```
dotnet build
```

E se for pra concluir tudo

```
dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained
```

---

Agora se for um DLL de fora mesmo você poderia editar o seu arquivo `.csproj` e adicionar (se sua hipotética dll estiver na mesma pasta do projeto):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    ...

    <ItemGroup>
         <Reference Include="MyAssembly">
              <HintPath>minha-dll.dll</HintPath>
         </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>

    ...

</Project>
```

Também deve copiar a DLL para as pastas da "compilação":

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    ...

    <ItemGroup>
         <Reference Include="MyAssembly">
              <HintPath>minha-dll.dll</HintPath>
         </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>

    ...

    <Target Name="CustomAfterPublish" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
        <Message Text="ProjectDir: $(ProjectDir)" Importance="high" />
        <Message Text="TargetDir: $(TargetDir)" Importance="high" />
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)minha-dll.dll" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" />
        <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)minha-dll.dll" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" />
    </Target>

    ...

</Project>
```

Mas claro, isso se for um DLL "externa" de fato, pra maioria dos casos tem no nuget e é só "compilar".

No VScode não precisa executar `dotnet restore`, ao baixar um projeto existente e se estiver configurado certo basta executar em <kbd>Run</kbd> que tudo será instalado automaticamente.

Geralmente o VSCode sugere instalar a extensão pra C#, mas se você esqueceu baixe:

- [**ms-dotnettools.csharp**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp)

Answer (score 9):

Encontrei uma extensão que facilita com a adição de DLLs. A [.NET Core Add Reference](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RafisTatar.addlocalnetreferences) é uma extensão que permite que você adicione uma dll ao seu projeto. Na guia de extensões é só procurar por esse nome acima ou clicar no link, depois é só aceitar, que abrirá o VS Code, depois é só instalar.

Para usar, aperte as teclas ctrl+shift+P e escreva ou selecione Add Local .Net References e dê , depois disso é só colar o caminho da dll que deseja adicionar ao seu projeto.

Detalhe,nesta extensão não é automatizada a parte de atualização da dll, então, você precisa limpar a referência com dotnet nuget locals global-packages --clear (esse comando limpa todas as referências locais), adicionar novamente a dll pelo ctrl+shift+P, depois digite o comando dotnet restore.

Fonte: https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-adicionar-referencia-de-dll-no-vscode-100552